# How to make a function identify another? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter, widget

So I have this code which create sort of like a form for users to fill on a Tkinter Canvas. In the space where they have to fill in their name, if they enter anything that is not an alphabet, I want my code to display an error message when they click the next button.
Here is a relevant piece of the code:

```
def check():

if not Name.isalpha():
    messagebox.showerror('Only letters', 'Only letters are allowed!')

def Per_Form():
    canvas.delete("all")
    root.configure(bg="cornflower blue")
    canvas.config(width=root.winfo_screenwidth(), height=root.winfo_screenheight(),
                 bg="cornflower blue")  # to horizontally center the rectangle
    form_title = canvas.create_rectangle(30, 20, 700, 75, fill="white", width=2)
    canvas.move(form_title, 300, 30)
    canvas.create_text(665, 70, text="Tell us more about you..")

    FirstName = Label(canvas, text="First Name")
    FirstName.configure(width=30, bg="white", fg="black", border=10)
    FirstName = canvas.create_window(330, 130, anchor=NW, window=FirstName)
FName_Entry = Entry(canvas)
    canvas.create_window(850, 145, window=FName_Entry, height=35, width=300)
    Name = FName_Entry.get()
.
.
.
.
   

 Next_button = Button(root, text="Next", anchor=CENTER, command=check)
    Next_button.configure(width=10, bg="black", fg="blue", border=10)
    Next_button = canvas.create_window(180, 200, anchor=NW, window=Next_button)
```

The code refuses to recognize the Name variable as it is in the `Per_Form` function. What do I do?

I have tried several variations of this but they dont work

Edit:

```
def check(Name):
    if not Name.isalpha():
        messagebox.showerror('Only letters', 'Only letters are allowed!')
    else:
        messagebox.showerror('Only letters', 'Perfect')


def Per_Form():
    canvas.delete("all")
    root.configure(bg="cornflower blue")
    canvas.config(width=root.winfo_screenwidth(), height=root.winfo_screenheight(),
                  bg="cornflower blue")  # to horizontally center the rectangle
    form_title = canvas.create_rectangle(30, 20, 700, 75, fill="white", width=2)
    canvas.move(form_title, 300, 30)
    canvas.create_text(665, 70, text="Tell us more about you..")

    FirstName = Label(canvas, text="First Name")
    FirstName.configure(width=30, bg="white", fg="black", border=10)
    FirstName = canvas.create_window(330, 130, anchor=NW, window=FirstName)

    FName_Entry = Entry(canvas)
    canvas.create_window(850, 145, window=FName_Entry, height=35, width=300)
    Name = FName_Entry.get()
.
.
.
.
Next_button = Button(root, text="Next", anchor=CENTER, command=lambda: check(Name))
    Next_button.configure(width=10, bg="black", fg="blue", border=10)
    Next_button = canvas.create_window(180, 200, anchor=NW, window=Next_button)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your if-statement isn't in the enclosed scope of your function, which makes your function empty and it will throw an error.
`def check():  if not Name.isalpha():  messagebox.showerror('Only letters', 'Only letters are allowed!')`

Then you don't parse the argument Name in your function so in your function Name will not known, which will throw an error.

`def check(name):`

Then you have the problem that you need to parse the argument but still don't want you function to be called immediately.

`Next button = Button(.., command= lambda: check(name))`

The last issue that it seems to have is that name will not be known at the point you created your button, since you have created that variable in your function. But I can't solve this issue for you as long as I don't see how you build the rest. But I think you can handle this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219523/discussion-on-answer-by-atlas435-how-to-make-a-function-identify-another-python).